# How solve ImportError: No module named 'dbus'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dbus, qtdbus

I have installed `anaconda4` on my ubuntu and I have these modules on my Python:

```
dbus-python (1.2.4)

gi (1.2)

pydbus (0.2)

QtAwesome (0.3.2)
qtconsole (4.2.0)
QtPy (1.0)

sip (4.18)
```

I tried installing `dbus-python (1.2.4)` and `pydbus (0.2)`, however, neither of them works!

After testing a simple program in python 3.5.1, an error appeared:

```
import dbus
system_bus = dbus.SystemBus()

ImportError: No module named 'dbus'
```

When I use `pydbus` in Python 2.7.11 and 3.5.1:

```
from pydbus import SystemBus

bus = SystemBus()
systemd = bus.get(".systemd1")

for unit in systemd.ListUnits():
    print(unit)
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named repository
```

The only thing that works is [this example](https://github.com/Werkov/PyQt4/tree/master/examples/dbus/pingpong) with `PyQT4` which I don't have any tutorial for.

What is the problem? Is it my installation or something else?

Comment: "*I've this modules on my python:*" - is that under 2.7 or 3.5?  Have you compared the two directory trees?  More than likely you have not installed everything into both.  I suggest you check the environment variables `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` (if it exists) when you do the install.

Answer (score 42):

Try this for Python 3.6 32 bit version

```
pip install dbus-python
```

Comment: I am using `conda` and `conda install -c conda-forge dbus-python` worked for me. Other answers didn't work in a `conda` environment.

Answer (score 32):

I don't know about installing dbus in anaconda but you can install it using apt-get in ubuntu .

```
sudo apt-get install python-dbus
```

I tried with pip earlier but that didn't work for me.

Comment: `sudo apt install  python3-dbus` for python 3

Comment: This is for debian based os(ubuntu in your case) [as Chetan answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46997001/4575793) ... but
@amit's command gave me `Package python-dbus is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
`

Answer (score 5):

I encountered same problem while installing `notify2` in `python3`
I was on MacOS 10.12
resolved using

```
brew install dbus
```

Comment: This is for MacOSX (and others) or basically all OS with homebrew installed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you installed the modules but this error most likely occurs because the module is not installed or not installed correctly. I would recommend the following for installing a module.

`pip install dbus`

or since you have anaconda this will also work

`conda install dbus`

If you are able to access and download the source code for instance on GitHub you can try the following two methods. Navigate to the source code directory then run the following commands in the terminal:

```
pip install setup.py
```

or

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

For more on installing packages from source distributions see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/install/) page.

Comment: I've tried pip install dbus, always got this error : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dbus (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for dbus

Comment: which  operation system do you use for dbus programming? you know i'm going crazy right now, why something this simple is giving me so much pain.

Comment: I have actually never used `dbus`. If you can download the source code you can use the source installation methods I added to the answer.

Comment: There is no package called `dbus` in pip. There is a `dbus-python` which did not install for me on anaconda3 complaining about `non-standard prefix`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when running an application called zeitgeist-explorer, but solved it by installing python2-dbus because the system was using version 3.5 and the application needed the 2 something version.
check this post if you are getting an error like this one
[fix import error no module named dbus](http://hongouru.blogspot.com/2016/07/solved-fix-importerror-no-module-named.html)

Answer (score 1):

pydbus requires python-gi (or python3-gi in the case of Python 3). And pydbus 0.2 is really outdated, 0.5.1 is the current version.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
sudo apt-get install python-dbus
```

on debian based os(ubuntu in your case) or

```
brew install dbus
```

on MacOSX

Comment: Duplicate to [this \[`brew`\]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40492625/4575793) and [this \[`apt-get`\]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37927053/4575793)

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing dbus-python. Also try on another virtual environment.

Comment: This advise seems to have already been given in nearly all of the previous answer to this question.

Comment: @Brian It was my re-iteration of may be same solution which will give more confidence to the later visitor of the same issue based on my experience. Happy life.